# Selenium WebDriver Java. Unable to locate image

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to determine the element of the below image/icon.

[image]

**Note: Other icons have the same //div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img' so i think i need another unique id to identify the exact element below. ID is dynamic btw**

Here's what i tried so far by using xpath:

1.) `//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img' and contains(@title,'Print Manager - Print Manager webpart allows the Lawson workspace user to contextually filter the print files of batch Jobs.')]`

2.) `//img[@title='Print Manager - Print Manager webpart allows the Lawson workspace user to contextually filter the print files of batch Jobs.']`

3.) `//img[contains(@title,'Print Manager - Print Manager webpart allows the Lawson workspace user to contextually filter the print files of batch Jobs.')]`

Any thoughts on this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath. First select the `div` and then the `img` tag within it.

```
"//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img']/img"
```

**EDIT 1:** If you want to fetch a specific image then you can fetch it by using the `id` attribute of the tag

```
"//img[@id='img_WebPartTitlect100_m_g_f26cdbcd_963c_46f4_94b1_c6a4fd7a9aab']"
```

Or by the index of its occurrence in sequence. (I'd recommend this one since it is much cleaner)

```
"(//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img']/img)[1]"
```

**EDIT 2:** Try using [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) to match the text partially.

```
"//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img']/img[contains(@title, 'Print Manager')]"
```

Comment: Hi the other icons on the image are in the same div class.. I think i have to look for the exact id of the element. updated the thread above.

Comment: `id` is dynamic.. The icon can be add and remove. the index of its occurrence can also change randomly. Can i not use the `@title` of the icon? I'm thinking of combining the `div class` and the `title`... but i already tried it. and it does not work also..

Comment: This works buddy. So the `@title "Print Manager"` alone can work. What I'm doing earlier is i'm including all of the description of `@title`. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: @user3713453 - Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element by ID

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imgId"));
```

Id's are unique, so you will have the specific element.

In your case `img_WebPartTitlect100...`, look for the `id` attribute after `src` attribute.

**Edit :**

You can also try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title*='Print Manager']"));
```

That will give you element with has title which contains "Print Manager".

Comment: @user3713453 I added another solution using title.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 1st image

```
//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img']/img[1]
```

If you want to 2nd image

```
//div[@class='infor-collapsed-icon-img']/img[2]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//img[@src='your source']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//table[@class='infor-collapsed-pane']/tr[1]/td//img
```